# Why does the compiler process a class function as non-static function?

Tags: c++

I am refreshing my C++ programming skills and I am reading Stroustrup's book to learn coding using STL and modern C++ idioms. I decided to start by writing a utility class `Date`, that should support basic date algebra. My `Useful::Date` class has some static functions, which I would like to call as `Date.is_bus_day()`, `Date.plus_b_days()`, `Date.plus_b_months()` and the like.

However, for some reason C++ seems to think that this function is non-static function instead of a class function. I can't figure out, why it is the case. I am aware that static methods can only access other static members of a class.

**The Date class**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    for (auto& el : vec)
    {
        os << el << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}

namespace Useful
{
    typedef int Day;
    typedef int Year;

    enum Month{
        January = 1,
        February = 2,
        March = 3,
        April = 4,
        May = 5,
        June = 6,
        July = 7,
        August = 8,
        September = 9,
        October = 10,
        November = 11,
        December = 12,
        JAN=1,
        FEB=2,
        MAR=3,
        APR=4,
        MAY=5,
        JUN=6,
        JUL=7,
        AUG=8,
        SEP=9,
        OCT=10,
        NOV=11,
        DEC=12
    };

    enum Weekday{
        Sunday = 0,
        Monday = 1,
        Tuesday = 2,
        Wednesday = 3,
        Thursday = 4,
        Friday = 5,
        Saturday = 6
    };

    class Date{
        private: 
            Day d;
            Month m;
            Year y;
        public:
            Date()
            {
                d = 01;
                m = JAN;
                y = 1970;
            }

            Date(Day d, int m, Year y) {
                this->d = d;
                this->m = Month(m);
                this->y = y;
            }

            friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Date& d);

            Day day_of_month()
            {
                return d;
            }

            //Day get_day_of_year()
            //{ ; }

            Month month()
            {
                return m;
            }

            Year year()
            {
                return y;
            }

            static bool is_leap_year(Date d)
            {
                return ((d.year() % 4 == 0) && (d.year() % 100 != 0)) || (d.year() % 400 == 0);
            }

            static Day end_of_month(Date d)
            {
                int e = 0;
                switch(d.month())
                {
                    case JAN :
                        e = 31;
                        break;
                    case FEB :
                        if(is_leap_year(d))
                            e = 29;
                        else
                            e= 28;
                        break;
                    case MAR :
                        e = 31;
                        break;
                    case APR :
                        e = 30;
                        break;
                    case MAY :
                        e = 31;
                        break;
                    case JUN :
                        e = 30;
                        break;
                    case JUL :
                        e = 31;
                        break;
                    case AUG :
                        e = 31;
                        break;
                    case SEP :
                        e = 30;
                        break;
                    case OCT :
                        e = 31;
                        break;
                    case NOV :
                        e = 30;
                        break;
                    case DEC :
                        e = 31;
                        break;
                }

                return e;
            }

            static bool is_end_of_month(Date date)
            {
                return (date.d == end_of_month(date));
            }
    };
```

**main() to test the Date class**

```
int main()
{
    Useful::Date d(01,06,2019);
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    std::cout << Useful::Date.end_of_month(d);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler complains in this case -

```
jdoodle.cpp: In function 'int main()':
jdoodle.cpp:169:30: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
std::cout << Useful::Date.end_of_month(d);
```

Comment: Scoped enumeration and using declarations are modern C++ idioms too. Use them.

Comment: `d.end_of_month(d);` is also possible. I believe it's normal style to make this sort of function a non-member instead, then you can just write `end_of_month(d);`

Comment: I think you got the "class function" terminology from Python. Please try to get out of the habit of transporting terminology across languages. "Class function" does not mean "static member function" in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static access is done with `::` [Scope Qualifier Operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/):

```
std::cout << Useful::Date::end_of_month(d);
```

(C++ is not Java)

Answer (score 0):

You should use scope resolution operator `::` for accessing static data members as well as static functions of a class in C++. The below line should work.

```
std::cout << Useful::Date::end_of_month(d);
```

Comment: What does this add to Michael's answer, which was posted 50 minutes before?